# Sort Stack Exchange search results by site?

Tags: feature-request, search, stackexchange.com

I searched for `perl` on Stack Exchange to see where questions about Perl were being asked. I would like to see the results sorted by site on Stack Exchange (and maybe a count for each site). I know most would be on Stack Overflow, and seeing where else questions about it are being asked and what makes the questions asked different on each site interest me.

Comment: Wouldn't the top results belong exclusively to one site, and the other sites be mostly invisible?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones If I look at the [search results for `perl`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+perl), the topmost entry (out of 93,786 entries) of "Is 'Perl Monger' derogatory when used by non Perl programmers?" is on English Language and Usage, has a score of 1, was asked five-and-a-half years ago, and `perl` was mentioned 4 times in the question. As far as I can tell, based on this, the results are completely random.

Comment: @JasonBassford My search wasn't as sophisticated. I just searched for ```perl`` in any context and got 297,296 results. It would be nice if there were a way to get a break down of SE sites where they are all coming from. It would be nice if there were a "sort by site" link, and have a drop-down appear with the list of sites in order of most to least where one clicks and sees the list of questions. So, if Stack Overflow has 250,000, it would be at the top and the singular post on English Language and Usage would be at the bottom. There could also be other sorts too.